# get phpunit config filename API function

Tags: php, phpunit, testcase

```
$ phpunit -c my-phpunit.xml
```

Is there an API php function made available by phpunit to know the name of the configuration file (my-phpunit.xml)?

For example:
TestCase::getConfFile()
phpunit_config_filename()
etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such API because tests should be oblivious to such details.